# ffmpeg after converting avi to mp4 need wait till video loads in flash player 100% otherwise video is buffering

Tags: php, ffmpeg

So if fixed all issues with my ffmpeg journey now I just need that after converting videos they play in flash player instantly and no need to wait till video loeaded 100% I use:

```
if ($success_msg) {
    $tmp_parts = explode('.', $file['name']);
    $ext = array_pop($tmp_parts);
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if($ext == "avi" && $convert_avi == true) {
        $convert_source = _VIDEOS_DIR_PATH.$new_name;
        $conv_name = substr(md5($file['name'].rand(1,888)), 2, 10).".mp4";
        $converted_file  = _VIDEOS_DIR_PATH.$conv_name;
        $ffmpeg_command = 'ffmpeg -i '.$convert_source.' -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -ar 44100 -async 44100 -r 29.970 -ac 2 -qscale 5 '.$converted_file;
        echo exec($ffmpeg_command);
        $sql = "UPDATE pm_temp SET url = '".$conv_name."' WHERE url = '".$new_name."' LIMIT 1";
        $result = @mysql_query($sql);
        unlink($convert_source);
    }
    echo $success_msg;
}
```

To convert videos

EDIT #1 ffmpeg concole output with faststart function:

```
root@1tb:~# ffmpeg -i sample.avi -movflags faststart -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -ar 44100 -async 44100 -r 29.970 -ac 2 -qscale 5 consample.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.7.15, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 22 2013 07:18:58 with gcc 4.4.5
  configuration: --enable-libdc1394 --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-Wall -g ' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-libdirac --disable-decoder=libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --extra-libs=-lgcrypt --disable-altivec --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-vis
  libavutil    50. 43. 0 / 50. 43. 0
  libavcodec   52.123. 0 / 52.123. 0
  libavformat  52.111. 0 / 52.111. 0
  libavdevice  52.  5. 0 / 52.  5. 0
  libavfilter   1. 80. 0 /  1. 80. 0
  libswscale    0. 14. 1 /  0. 14. 1
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
[mp3 @ 0x15389100] Header missing
[mpeg4 @ 0x15386dc0] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
Input #0, avi, from 'sample.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2540/release)
  Duration: 00:01:01.81, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1194 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 640x352 [PAR 1:1 DAR 20:11], 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
[MOV/3GP/MP4/3G2 muxer @ 0x15386c80] [Eval @ 0x7ffffec71230] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'faststart'
[MOV/3GP/MP4/3G2 muxer @ 0x15386c80] Unable to parse option value "faststart"
Invalid value 'movflags' for option 'faststart'
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: when i convert 170 mb video for example i need to wait till that video lods in flash player 100% and with other videos it instalty playes and loads i want that with converted videos would be the same.

Comment: ffmpeg 0.7 is really old. And hence does not support faststart`. Get a newer release. Actually, it was introduced in 1.0, it seems `git describe --contains a714150827c70f8baf2ec42dfecd9363c17e803d: n1.0~14`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use [`-movflags faststart`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#MOV_002fMP4_002fISMV) to avoid the player having to buffer the whole video.

Normally the the internal index of the mp4 would be written to the end of the file (as it is not known/complete while still processing the file). `faststart` will do another muxer pass to move that index once complete to the front, so that the player can read it without reading the whole file first.

Make sure your ffmpeg build is new enough to support this.

Example:

```
# -strict 2 just for allowing the aac encoder. 
$ ffmpeg -i in.mkv -strict -2 -movflags faststart out.mp4
ffmpeg version 57577-g83b8d74 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 28 2013 15:31:30 with Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'in.mkv':
  Duration: 00:00:23.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x716 [SAR 1:1 DAR 320:179], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (default)
...
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x716 [SAR 1:1 DAR 320:179], q=-1--1, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 -> aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
...   
[mp4 @ 0x7f9c44016e00] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
...
video:5426kB audio:361kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.291754%
...
```

Since your ffmpeg is old, you might have better luck using `qt-faststart` instead of ffmpeg itself. There is a `tools/qt-faststart.c` in ffmpeg since 0.5 (or something), which you can compile `cc -o qt-faststart tools/qt-faststart.c` and use `./qt-faststart in.mp4 out.mp4`.

Comment: when i use this function no video is converted at all in in fst it weights 0kb maybe can u give me some example maybe i dont use this functionn how i should ?

Comment: yep im using :
 $ffmpeg_command = 'ffmpeg -i '.$convert_source.' -movflags faststart -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -ar 44100 -async 44100 -r 29.970 -ac 2 -qscale 5 '.$converted_file;

and file dont converts anymore and it waith at ftp 0kbbut it is in mp4 toigh but not converting this is php problem?

Comment: @XenosTrojanowicz Without your console output it is impossible to determine the issue. Perhaps your ffmpeg is too old. Refer to you local documentation to see if you even have this option (note that the online docs are synced to the latest ffmpeg code in Git master).

Comment: i edited my topic with ffmpeg output but it seems that fastart is not enabled or missing so problem is that my ffmpeg is too old or i need to enable some function?

Comment: Added info about qt-faststart

Comment: ok i installed qt-faststart ffmpeg plugin but maybe u can give example hot to use it to convert videos becose i dont know but qt-faststart is installed i check in terminal with which qt-faststart and it respondes
/usr/bin/qt-faststart

Comment: i decided to renew my ffmpeg so u already gave me 2 choises thank you for your time :)